# How to use custom visual styles in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, themes

How can I use custom (non-official) visual styles in Windows XP?

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to use custom themes, you need to patch your system with a tool like Uxtheme Multi-patcher. Read the following Lifehacker article for full instructions:

[How to Use Custom Windows Visual Styles](http://lifehacker.com/#!5056544/how-to-use-custom-windows-visual-styles)